# I have different results in for and stream, why?

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

I have Flyweight pattern and i try to convert for looping to stream but the result is different:

```
public Line getLine(Color color) {
    for(Line line: pool) {
        if(line.getColor().equals(color)) {
            return line;
        } 
    }        
    return createLine(color);
}

factory.getLine(Color.RED);
factory.getLine(Color.RED);
System.out.println(getPool().size()); // print 1
```

Refactored code:

```
public Line getLine(Color color) {
    return pool.stream()
               .filter(l -> l.getColor().equals(color))                   
               .findFirst()                   
               .orElse(createLine(color));
}

factory.getLine(Color.RED);
factory.getLine(Color.RED);
System.out.println(getPool().size()); // print 2
```

What's wrong with the stream?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  Tell us what behavior you want, and what behavior you're actually getting.  Include the exact wording of any error message you are receiving, and specify the line of code that's causing the error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `createLine` adds to `pool`, this

```
.orElse(createLine(color));
```

first invokes `createLine(color)`, then passes the result to `orElse(T)` which gets invoked.

You are probably looking for [`orElseGet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) with a `Supplier` that will call `createLine(color)`.

```
orElseGet(() -> createLine(color));
```